# How to check where in a menu tree a node is & then display a portion of the tree?

Tags: routes

How can I check where in a menu tree a node is, and in particular how can I determine what its ultimate parent is? And how can I display a portion of a menu tree? Here's an example menu tree to illustrate:

```
m1
-subm2
--subsubm3
-subm4
m5
-subm6
```

If I were on the pages linked to from items 1-4, I'd want to find out that the ultimate parent of these items is m1, and then display only the portion of the menu below m1, ie:

```
m1
-subm2
--subsubm3
-subm4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) will do what you need. I have used this module to display portions of menus only under one parent item as you mention and it worked great. It's for Drupal 6 & 7 as well.

Comment: Upvoted as that seems a brilliant answer to my 2nd question as I can extract the relevant code from the module - thanks! Would still love an answer from anyone to my 1st question: "How can I check where in a menu tree a node is, and in particular how can I determine what it's ultimate parent is?"

Comment: Glad Menu Block will do the trick. As for your first question, I'm not sure, but could it be possible to do a query for the menu's active trail / acive item (which is embedded in the rendered HTML) with JQuery and then spit that back out? Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Clever idea! But that'd get inelegant and complicated - I'd have to print all the possible sub-trees, hide them with CSS, and then unhide one with JQuery. So I'll hold out for someone coming up with a way to do this with PHP.

Comment: Now I'm not sure how this differs than what you are trying to do with Menu Block. For example, that can print out subtrees as a sidebar block.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're not sure :) My outstanding 1st question was: "How can I check where in a menu tree a node is, and in particular how can I determine what it's ultimate parent is?" Your answer in your comment was to write some jquery which'd detect the active item and show only the menu portion containing it, but I thought that sounded a bit complex.

Comment: Ah, trying it out I see more what you mean - it's an ingenious approach, I'll probably accept it once I get it working.

Comment: So it turns out Menu Block provides an even simpler way to achieve what I want. In the block configuration I make 'Starting level' be '2nd'.

Comment: ok, glad you sorted it out. You may also want to check out: http://drupal.org/project/menu_position, it's a nice complement.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that Menu Block can't *quite* do what I'm after - see my question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29887/menu-block-or-custom-menu-display-expand-immediate-children-of-active-item