# Menu Block (or custom menu display): expand immediate children of active item

Tags: routes, blocks

I need to show a menu which only displays nodes one or two levels into the menu hierarchy, unless these nodes are immediate children of the node currently being viewed, in which case they should also be shown. (I explain what I'm after more fully in the lengthy 'example' below.) The [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module almost lets me do this, but lacks a setting to expand the immediate children of active item. I [added this as a feature request for Menu Block](http://drupal.org/node/1533218) but have had no reply. Is there any way I can implement this myself, either using Menu Block or writing code to display the menus myself? Any code pointers would be very helpful.

(*Background info:* I'm using Drupal 7)

## **An example of what I'm after**

Suppose you have a menu with these items (with the number of dashes before them representing their level):

```
-i1
--i2
--i3
---i4
---i5
----i6
--i7
```

If in Menu Block I set my menu block up with 'Starting level' = '1st level' and 'Maximum depth'=1 then it'll look like:

```
-i1
--i2
--i3
--i7
```

However, I'd like there to be an 'expand the immediate children of the active item' setting in Menu Block. If this setting were chosen then if the active item were i3 or i4 you should see:

```
-i1
--i2
--i3
---i4
---i5
--i7
```

And if it were i5 or i6 you'd see:

```
-i1
--i2
--i3
---i4
---i5
----i6
--i7
```

Comment: Isn't this pretty much what you would get with a unlimited maximum depth menu?

Comment: does it apply to D7? There are no tags now related to the actual Drupal version. :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter yes (though I was following this site's guideline that 'Version tags should be used only when strictly necessary, and not used just to report "I am using Drupal 7 in my site."' :-)

Comment: @Dooshta No it's not - if you look at http://cea-gwwc-alex1.philosofiles.com/resources/recommended-charities.php you'll see nodes like 'health' showing in the Menu Block in the red left sidebar. This Menu Block has  'Maximum depth' set to 'Unlimited'. You can therefore see the root menu items grandchildren like 'Health', but I don't want you to be able to unless you're on the 'Charity Comparisons' page, or indeed the 'Health' page. So as you can see 'Maximum depth'='Unlimited' doesn't achieve this.

Comment: @tog22: [if you think about this one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/7/info), there's another sentence too: "Use 7 only on questions that are specific for features implemented in Drupal 7." - and your question can be a version-specific problem as the code you have to apply for doing these modifications can hugely depend on Drupal's version. I think the suggestion not setting version-specific tags can refer to general questions like "suggestions to boost Drupal's performance", etc.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter thanks for pointing that out. I'm happy for someone who knows this site's conventions better than me to tag my question with '7' if that'd help get an answer!

Comment: @tog22 What you are describing is normal menu behavior in Drupal. To get the menu to show up like on the site you linked you'd have to set the menu links to "show as expanded". If that option is not checked for any menu items then you should have the menu behave the way you want.

Comment: @tog22: Dooshta is right, your menus are set to be expanded by default OR are overridden by a module. Can you post a screenshot of your menu block's settings? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right, I hadn't properly understood the 'Expand all children of this tree' within Menu Block. I had it checked: http://imgur.com/SRZHt . I've now unchecked it, and it works as you can see at http://cea-gwwc-alex1.philosofiles.com/resources/recommended-charities.php . Do answer my question if you want to claim the rep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like we figured out in the comments the problem was that the "Expand all children of this tree" option was checked for the menu block. Without checking this the children will only be shown if the user is on a related page, which was the desired result.